# Using RecursiveIterator to flatten my multi array not working?

Tags: php

This returns null even if the input array is not null:

```
function flattenArray($multi_array)
{ 
  $flat_array = array();
  foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($multi_array)) as $k => $v) 
  { 
    $flat_array[$k] = $v;
  }

  return $flat_array;
}
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Anyway, look into the second option of the RecursiveIteratorIterator constructor.  You'll want to use the RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST flag.

Comment: What is an example of an array that you are passing? What is an example of the desired output?

Comment: The function would return NULL (due to a thrown exception) if you didn't give it an array. If you really want to determine the problem, please provide a sample input array that displays the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on PHP 5.4:

```
function flattenArray($multi_array)
{
  return iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
      new RecursiveArrayIterator($multi_array)), false
  );
}

var_dump(flattenArray([1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7], 8], 9]));
```

Partial output:

```
array(9) {
  [0] =>
  int(1)
  [1] =>
  int(2)
  [2] =>
  int(3)
  [3] =>
  int(4)
```

The only problem with your code snippet from what I can tell is that the keys are overwritten.

Comment: Overwriting keys does not explain NULL I'd say, but I'm not sure as well about the exact problem OP has. Some exemplary input values would be helpful with the question.